# Is a self promoting or spammy profile a problem?

Tags: discussion, user-accounts, spam, profile-page

A new HE user has put promotional web links and phone numbers in his bio. Is this a problem?

The details: here's his HE bio:

https://diy.stackexchange.com/users/112311/chris-jackson

His StackOverflow bio is even more explicit, linking him to Best Access Doors:

https://stackoverflow.com/users/12791368/chris-jackson

... which he seems to be part of:

https://ca.linkedin.com/in/chrisjbestacc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see absolutely nothing wrong with this. Self-promotion is **normal**. That is **not** the same as "spam". Spam refers specifically to unsolicited commercial email and, more generically (at least in SE context) to posting *answers* that are self-promoting. But:

- Even just a "real name" is enough to be self-promotion in some situations - Google can find anyone/anything in an instant
- Self-promotion within an answer is discouraged but I think it is OK when clearly marked (not "hidden" behind "hey, I tried this web site...") and appropriate (e.g., posting info. about access doors on a question about toilets or light bulbs would not be OK). A profile isn't a problem at all.
- Any reference to products/web sites (unless totally fake like "unicorns") should be something that at least passes the smell test. In this case, the linked web sites appear to be selling real products. In fact, while I don't see the connection to general Stackoverflow, it seems like the type of stuff that **is** appropriate to link to a profile for DIY.
- Multilevel marketing and certain other things are problematic. No indication of that here, at least not at first glance.
- The SO profile even says "SEO at". No funny stuff. Just trying to promote a web site.

Answer (score 2):

My understanding is that users can put what they want in to their profile page(s). It does of course have to be limited so as to not be offensive and not violate the rights of others.

Keep in mind that it is a choice to go look at someone's profile page.